# How to auto add imports in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

I am new to IntelliJ. I am writing some code and am seeing IntelliJ complain that it can't resolve a class/object:

[image]

It knows to suggest which import to add but I'm looking for a shortcut that will allow me to say "*Yes, please auto add that import!*". In Eclipse, this is as easy as `Cmd+Shift+O`...any ideas here?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/keyboard-shortcuts-you-cannot-miss.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Alt-Enter` is the shortcut. Actually it's general shortcut for fixing problems which the IDE understands.